# isinstance(foo,bar) vs type(foo) is bar

Tags: python, typechecking

A question of semantics, really.

Up until recently, if I had to do any typechecking on a structure, I would use `type(obj) is list` et. al. However since joining SO I've noticed everyone (and I mean *EVERYONE*) uses `isinstance(obj,list)` instead. It seems they are synonymous, and `timeit` reveals almost IDENTICAL speed between them.

```
def a(): return type(list()) is list
def b(): return isinstance(list(),list)

from timeit import timeit
timeit(a)
# 0.5239454597495582
timeit(b)
# 0.5021292075273176
```

Indeed even `dis` agrees they're synonymous, with the exception of `type is`'s `COMPARE_OP`

```
from dis import dis

dis(a)
# 2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (type) 
#             3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (list) 
#             6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
#             9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
#            12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (list) 
#            15 COMPARE_OP               8 (is) 
#            18 RETURN_VALUE

dis(b)
# 2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (isinstance)
#             3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (list) 
#             6 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
#             9 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (list) 
#            12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
#            15 RETURN_VALUE
```

I frankly find it more readable to say `if type(foo) is list:` than `if isinstance(foo,list):`, the first is basically just pseudo-code and the second calls some function (which I have to look up every time to be `isinstance` or `instanceof`) with some arguments. It doesn't look like a type cast, and there's no explicit way of knowing whether `isinstance(a,b)` is checking if `b` is an instance of `a` or vice-versa.

I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python) that we use `isinstance` because it's nicer about inheritance. `type(ClassDerivedFromList) is list` will fail while `isinstance(ClassDerivedFromList,list)` will succeed. But if I'm checking what should ALWAYS BE A BASE OBJECT, what do I really lose from doing `type is`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> if I'm checking what should ALWAYS BE A BASE OBJECT, what do I really lose from doing type is?

well, it's nice you give the full documented answer in your question, so your answer is you lose *nothing*! The only times where `isinstance()` is necessary is when checking inheritance of a given class compared to another, as you well said and referenced. `type()` shall be only used to check whether an instance is *exactly* of a given base type.

Comment: I'm specifically thinking about refactoring a function I wrote about 6 months ago that accepts either a string or a list of strings. The only input to that function will EVER be a `str` or a `list`, so is doing `if type(foo) is str: _handle_str(foo) else: _handle_list(foo)` really bad practice?

Comment: @adsmith: do you use Python 3?  If not, your code just broke if you wind up with a unicode string.

Comment: @DSM I do, but I do appreciate the pitfalls of `unicode` vs `str`.

Comment: or `isinstance(foo, (str,unicode))` for that matter!

Comment: or you could simply do `if type(foo) is list: _handle_list(foo) else: _handle_str(foo)`. @DSM is totally right, to handle strings correctly, you need to check `isinstance(foo, basestring)`. And if I were you I'd actually check `if type(foo) is list: _handle_list(foo) elif isinstance(foo, basestring): _handle_str(foo) else raise Exception("Type Not Handled")`.

Comment: Your lib will be more easily adopted by others, or migrated to new features, if you are more tolerant of other sequence types than just list, most notably tuple and set. Accepting generator expressions in place of your list is also forward-thinking.

Comment: indeed, instead of `type(list)`, checking if it's an instance of iterable is always a better idea ☺

Answer (score 5):

Other than the inheritance issue, you also lose the ability to test multiple types when using `isinstance`. For example:

```
def chk(typ):
    if not isinstance(typ, (str, int)):
        raise ValueError('typ must be string or int')
    ...
```

Comment: You can always do  `type(x) in (str, int)`.

Answer (score 5):

The [Python Docs for the built-in type function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) provide clear guidance on the difference between type (with one arg) and isinstance.

*With one argument, return the type of an object. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by object.**class**.
The isinstance() built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.*

To illustrate, take a look at the inheritance hierarchy below in module diamond:

[image]

Then take a look at the python console output below based on module diamond:

[image]

As per the documentation, it is more versatile and can cover a wider range of scenarios. With respect to the OP's original question - the performance characteristics were not stated as a valid reason to favour one over the other. Neither was readability.

For a more in-depth discussion, which includes an explanation on (in the words of the answerer) *"why checking type equality is an even worse practice in recent Python versions than it already used to be"*, please see this highly voted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/1882064)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the only part of the question you talk about here is one that I answer in my question. "I understand...that we use `isinstance` because it's nicer about inheritance. `type(ClassDerivedFromList) is list` will fail while `isinstance(ClassDerivedFromList, list)` will succeed"

Comment: @AdamSmith - as pointed out in my answer, the docs clearly explain the difference. " The isinstance() built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account."  I am clarifying your uncertainty - and why you had noticed it was overwhelmingly the popular choice. It is more versatile and can cover a wider range of scenarios - type() would suffice where you know the exact type. Also wished to illustrate this answer with some code examples to clarify for others.

Comment: If you down-vote, I would be grateful if you could offer an explanation so I can amend / improve the answer if deemed necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this answer is specifically about the part the question explicitly did not ask about. Seems pretty weird to me. The question asks specifically about the situation when one wants to test an exact type, and the answer talks about how `isinstance` is better when one doesn't want to test an exact type.

Comment: My point exactly, thanks for the helpful comment - isInstance is more versatile hence the popularity. performance characteristics were not stated as a reason to favour one over the other. Hence most people opt for the more versatile option unless they "need" to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## type(x) doesn't work with mypy

At least for me, the main reason for preferring `isinstance` over `type(x)` is because mypy can infer types from `isinstance` checks but it can't with `type(x)`. From the docs:

> Mypy can usually infer the types correctly when using isinstance type
> tests, but for other kinds of checks you may need to add an explicit
> type cast:

```
def f(o: object) -> None:
    if type(o) is int:
        o = cast(int, o)
        g(o + 1)    # This would be an error without the cast
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Source: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html?highlight=isinstance#complex-type-tests

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is:
No, given that you're checking for a definite base class, as you loose the ability to test for inherited classes.

And IMO `isinstance` is nicer to read and in Python: Readability counts.

PS: I'm getting a significant difference in timings (on Python 3.3)

```
      type: 0.5241982917936874  
isinstance: 0.46066255811928847
```

Comment: You find `isinstance(foo,list)` to be easier to read than `type(foo) is list` ??