# How to count the number of instances of a class within a list?

Tags: python

I have a list that I am appending different objects to.

How would I find the total number of instances of a specific class within that list please?

Comment: by writing some code I guess.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide the code/variables you have trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(sum([1 for x in llist if isinstance(x, my_class)]))
```

Comment: you need double equal signs to check equality `==`. And I would go with `isinstance()` like `isinstance(x, my_class)`

Comment: could you justify how isinstance(x, my_class) might be a better option than the usage of type() == ?

Comment: This is a fair question.. I have only used (and saw used) `type` only to check against *variable types* (which are also classes) but never to check for custom classes (user-defined ones). So it is more a matter or what my eye and probably many other eyes are used to seeing.

Comment: It appears that [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type) recommend the use of isinstance()

Comment: [`type` vs `isinstance`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894575/isinstancefoo-bar-vs-typefoo-is-bar) or better yet [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python)