# Python how to check the type of a variable

Tags: python

Basically, I need to check the type of data of which a variable is storing before replacing the data stored in the variable with the new data. For example, how to check if the variable is storing a string data or an integer data?

Source Code:

```
class Toy:

    #Toy Class Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        Name = "Train Engine";
        ID = "TE11";
        Price = 0.99;
        Minimum_Age = 4;

    #Return Name
    def Return_Name(self):
        print(Name)
        return Name

    #Set Name
    def Set_Name(self, Variable):
        #This is where I would need to check the type of data that the variable 'Variable' is currently storing.
        Name = Variable

    #Return ID
    def Return_ID(self):
        print(ID)
        return ID

    #Set ID
    def Set_ID(self, Variable):
        #This is where I would need to check the type of data that the variable 'Variable' is currently storing.
        ID = Variable

    #Return Price
    def Return_Price(self):
        print(Price)
        return Price

    #Set Price
    def Set_Price(self, Variable):
        #This is where I would need to check the type of data that the variable 'Variable' is currently storing.
        Price = Variable

    #Return Minimum_Age
    def print_Minimum_Age(self):
        print(Minimum_Age)
        return Minimum_Age

    #Set Minimum_Age
    def Set_Minimum_Age(self, Variable):
        #This is where I would need to check the type of data that the variable 'Variable' is currently storing.
        Minimum_Age = Variable
```

So basically, how should I, or are there any conventional way to check the type of data that the variable is storing?

Comment: You can use `type`.

Comment: `type(variable_name)` use it

Comment: The only times where isinstance() is necessary is when checking inheritance of a given class compared to another, as you well said and referenced. type() shall be only used to check whether an instance is exactly of a given base type. thanks to @zmo here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894575/isinstancefoo-bar-vs-typefoo-is-bar

Comment: There is a subtle distinction here: variables don't have types, *values* do.

Comment: Why do you need to store either a string or an integer in `Name` (which, by the way, needs to be an instance attribute, not a local variable)? A better approach would be for `Set_Name` to *accept* either a string or integer, but only *store* a value of a single type, converting one to the other as necessary.

Comment: The point is somewhat moot; in Python, you typically don't bother with such trivial getter and setter methods; just assign to and read from the attributes directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper way to do this is [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
if isinstance(variable, MyClass)
```

But think twice if you actually need this. Python uses duck-typing, so explicit checks for types is not always a good idea. If you still want to do so, consider using some [abstract base](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) or minimal valuable type for your checks.

As other people suggesting, just getting type of your variable can be done by `type(variable)`, but in most cases its better to use `isinstance`, because this will make your code polymorphic - you'll automatically support instances of subclasses of target type.

Comment: So basically if I want to check the data type of a string, then I would use 'isinstance(Variable, str)' ?

Comment: In python3 - yes. In python2 - `isinstance(var, basesting)` in most cases — to operate with `str` as well as with `unicode`

Comment: Thanks, that did the deal

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the type of a variable, and don't want to support inheriting, use the built-in [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function:

```
if type(variable) is MyClass:
    ...
```

I agree with [@Slam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2161778/slam), that you should use this responsibly.

Answer (score 0):

`type(variable_name)` returns the type of the variable

Answer (score 0):

`type(variable)`

This command will return the type of the data stored by the variable.